# Function is being called twice

Tags: javascript, debugging

First of all sorry for the long snippet that's coming. 
I have a function that calls an update function and applies it a value as a string with + "px", it also prints success. My problem is that this function is being called twice. (Really sorry if my question formulation is bad I'm a beginner and trying my best :/)

```
    var repValue = 0;
    var x = 0;

    function checkAnswer(one) {
        if (one === 1) {
            update((repValue += 3) + "px");
            console.log("success"); 
    } else { alert("hello"); }
}
```

The update function:

```
function update(repBar) {

    document.querySelector(".rep").style.width = repBar;

}
```

I have my Event Listener:

```
     function listeners(nextPage) {
            document.getElementById("goodAnswer").addEventListener("click", function () {
            x = 1;
            nextPage();
        })
}
```

When it triggers we go to page two and call checkAnswer which then calls update it will print success:

```
function pageTwo() {
checkAnswer(x);
listeners(pageThree);
}
```

But when my EventListener calls pageThree it will then call checkAnswer and it will print success two time. That is my problem.

```
function pageThree() {
checkAnswer(x);
}
```

full code simple version:

```
 var repValue = 0;
        var x = 0;

        function checkAnswer(one) {
            if (one === 1) {
                update((repValue += 3) + "px");
                console.log("success"); 
        } else { alert("hello"); }
    }

 function update(repBar) {

        document.querySelector(".rep").style.width = repBar;

    }


         function listeners(nextPage) {
                document.getElementById("goodAnswer").addEventListener("click", function () {
                x = 1;
                nextPage();
            })
    }



function init() {

listeners(pageOne);

function pageOne() {

        checkAnswer123(x);
        listeners(pageTwo);

}

 function pageTwo() {

        checkAnswer123(x);
        listeners(pageThree);

}


}

init();
```

Full Code:

```
// Rep Width
var rep = document.querySelector(".rep").style.width = "2px";
repValue = "7px";

var answerOne = document.getElementById("goodAnswer");
var answerTwo = document.getElementById("mildAnswer");
var answerThree = document.getElementById("badAnswer");


var omniBlock = document.querySelector(".textDown");
var bb;

var x;
var y;
var z;

//hide avatars
document.querySelector(".avatar1").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar2").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar3").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar4").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar5").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar6").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar7").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(".avatar8").style.display = "none";


document.getElementById("goodAnswer").style.borderStyle = "none";

document.getElementById("mildAnswer").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("badAnswer").style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("mildAnswer").style.borderStyle = "none";
document.getElementById("badAnswer").style.borderStyle = "none";


//Sets textdown as empty at the start of the game
document.querySelector(".textDown").innerHTML = "";
document.querySelector(".textUp").innerHTML = "";
//Sets Good answer text as empty
document.getElementById("goodAnswer").innerHTML = "";
AnswerText = document.getElementById("goodAnswer");

function changeBorderColor(psc) {
    var answerColor = document.getElementById("goodAnswer").style.border = psc;
}

var stanleyDefaultText = document.querySelector(".textUp");

var greenBorder = "1px solid green";
var redBorder = "1px solid red";
var orangeBorder = "1px solid orange";
var noBorder = "0px solid white";


//stanley Text
function stanleyText(text, timeout) {
    //Types stanley's text
    var typewriterStanley = new Typewriter(stanleyDefaultText, {
        delay: 1,
        cursor: ""
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        typewriterStanley.typeString(text).start();
    }, timeout);



}
//Show Omni possible answers
function omniTextAnswers(answer1, answer2, answer3, timeout) {
    setTimeout(
        document.getElementById("goodAnswer").innerHTML = answer1,
        document.getElementById("mildAnswer").innerHTML = answer2,
        document.getElementById("badAnswer").innerHTML = answer3, timeout);
}

function omniText(text, timeout, bordercolor, timeout2) {
    //Types omnis text
    var typewriterOmni = new Typewriter(omniBlock, {
        delay: 12,
        cursor: "|"
    });

    typewriterOmni.typeString(text)

        .start();
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById(bb).style.border = bordercolor;
    }, timeout2);

}
//Event Listeners
function listeners(nextPage) {

    document.getElementById("goodAnswer").addEventListener("click", function () {
        x = 1;
        rightText = answerOne.innerHTML;
        bb = "goodAnswer";
        nextPage();
    })
    document.getElementById("mildAnswer").addEventListener("click", function () {
        x = 2;
        rightText = answerTwo.innerHTML;
        bb = "mildAnswer";
        nextPage();
    })
    document.getElementById("badAnswer").addEventListener("click", function () {
        x = 3;
        rightText = answerThree.innerHTML;
        bb = "badAnswer";
        nextPage();
    })
}
//Update Rep + Answer border + emptys answers
function update(borderstyle, repBar) {
    //Set answer color
    var answerColor = document.getElementById(bb).style.border = borderstyle;
    var rep = document.querySelector(".rep").style.width = repBar;
    //Sets answers text to empty
    answerOne.innerHTML = "";
    answerTwo.innerHTML = "";
    answerThree.innerHTML = "";
    repValue = repBar;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    return repBar;

}

function checkAnswer123(one) {
    if (one === 1) {
        update("1px solid green", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("3px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 2) {
        update("1px solid orange", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("2px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 3) {
        update("1px solid red");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }



}

function checkAnswer213(one) {
    if (one === 2) {
        update("1px solid green", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("3px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 1) {
        update("1px solid orange", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("2px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 3) {
        update("1px solid red");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }



}

function checkAnswer312(one) {

    if (one === 3) {
        update("1px solid green", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("3px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 1) {
        update("1px solid orange", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("2px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 2) {
        update("1px solid red");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }



}

function checkAnswer231(one) {
    if (one === 2) {
        update("1px solid green", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("3px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 3) {
        update("1px solid orange", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("2px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 1) {
        update("1px solid red");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }



}

function checkAnswer132(one) {
    if (one === 1) {
        update("1px solid green", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("3px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 3) {
        update("1px solid orange", parseInt(repValue, 10) + parseInt("2px", 10) + "px");
    } else if (one === 2) {
        update("1px solid red");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }



}



function init() {

    stanleyText("Omni, things aren't going well here...<br><br> What are your thougths on the situation?");
    omniTextAnswers("What is the situation again?", "", "", 1500);
    listeners(pageOne);


    function pageOne() {

        checkAnswer123(x);

        omniText("What is the situation again?", null, "0px solid green", 0300);
        stanleyText("Reputable members have been posting fake information about you, they say you've been dissing the community and mocking them.<br><br> They are leaving the forums, 300 members just today...", 1200)
        omniTextAnswers("What do you suggest Stanley?", "", "", 4500);
        listeners(pageTwo);

    }

    function pageTwo() {

        checkAnswer123(x);
        omniText("What do you suggest Stanley?", null, "0px solid green", 0300)
        stanleyText("I'll be showing you members posts, try your best to earn you reputation by participating!", 1200);
        omniTextAnswers("I hate this suggestion already. But let's go, I do care about my community.", "", "", 1200);
        listeners(pageThree);


    }

    function pageThree() {
        document.querySelector(".avatar1").style.display = "";
        checkAnswer123(x);
        omniText("I hate this suggestion already. But let's go, I do care about my community.", null, "0px solid green", 0300)
        stanleyText("I've heard some motivational speeches before, and I somewhat still assert them in my life. I've always been a happy go lucky dude regardless, but when times get 10 kinds of damn that's rough, I don't break down like I'm sure tons of people would. Kevin Hart is a pretty inspiring dude, works out everyday etc. He's a pretty strong dude upstairs, and easy to relate to. I can vibe to it, check him out.", 1500);
        document.getElementById("mildAnswer").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("badAnswer").style.display = "";
        omniTextAnswers("How can he be so small and laugh so loud?", "Kevin Heart does seem like a legit guy.", "I'm banning you for posting about someone I don't care about. Fugg you.", 1200);
        listeners(pageFour)

    }

    function pageFour() {
        document.querySelector(".avatarStanley").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".avatar1").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".avatar2").style.display = "";
        checkAnswer213(x);
        omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
        stanleyText("Hey guys, Englishman here, after speaking to several Europeans online, I have decided I want to learn a new language. I was thinking of learning French since I already know a little and I like French girls and the culture (not that it's my motivation) but what do you guys recommend to me to use, like I know there are loads of free websites/apps but I'm unsure at which ones are the best. <br><br>Hope HF users are staying safe during this time", 1200);
        omniTextAnswers("Know how you say shut up in french? SHUT THE FUCK UP.", "Don't have time for that nonsense.", "Good luck with you learning.")
        listeners(pageFive)
    }

    function pageFive() {

        document.querySelector(".avatar2").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".avatar3").style.display = "";
        checkAnswer123(x);
        omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
        stanleyText("Hello, <br><br>I would like to hear about ya'll what you think about the saying \"Money doesn't make happy\". <br>Personally I think it's bullsnap, money does make happy and there isn't a cap on \"how much\" would make me happy. The freedom it offers is sufficient enough to make me live a happy and stress free life.", 1000);
        omniTextAnswers("Money is important, but it won't assure you happiness.", "I've got a lot of money and can't complain", "I'm rich and very happy, not like you peasant.")
        listeners(pageSix);
    }

    function pageSix() {
        document.querySelector(".avatar3").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".avatar4").style.display = "";
        checkAnswer123(x);
        omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
        stanleyText("I have been working this side hustle since April 7th. My personal finances have been taken care of and I was able to save up $5,000 before the end of the second month of this venture.My goal is to accumulate $10,000 into savings by August 1st. Afterwards I will invest it and treat the fund as a nest egg for my business.", 1000);
        omniTextAnswers("5000, in two month? What were you wanking all day?", "Congratulations, make sure to spend it wisely.", "Pfu, I make that in a hour")
        listeners(pageSeven);
    }

    function pageSeven() {
        document.querySelector(".avatar4").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".avatar5").style.display = "";
        checkAnswer213(x);
        omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
        stanleyText("Hey guys :) <br><br> Just upgraded to Ub3r! Today is actually my 60th day on HF. Lovin it so far! <br><br>Yall got any tips, tricks, or handy things I should know about now that I've upgraded? <br><br>What do yall like best about Ub3r?", 1000)
        omniTextAnswers("If I was still reviewing Uber applications you would have been denied.", "Congrats on Uber, continue doing HQ posts.", "Uber is easy to get now.")
        listeners(pageHeight);

    }

    function pageHeight() {

        document.querySelector(".avatar5").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".avatar6").style.display = "";
        checkAnswer231(x);
        omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
        stanleyText("So everyday for the last 150 days straight I've checked in on the daily thread, however today I didn't get any Bytes for my check-in post. <br><br>I've checked the thread and I've posted 4 separate times, and my Bytes history page shows nothing for today's check-in, just my most recent sports wagers.<br><br>Any idea why this would be happening? Not a huge deal as it's only 25 Bytes, I'm more-so posting this so Staff are aware of the issue, not sure if any others have encountered it or not.<br><br>Thanks guys!",1000)
        omniTextAnswers("I'll be checking into this, will get back to you.", "What, are you going to cry for 25 bytes?", "I'll fix this one day.")
        listeners(pageNine);
    }

function pageNine() {
    document.querySelector(".avatar6").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".avatar7").style.display = "";
    checkAnswer132(x);
    omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
    stanleyText("I'm sure this has been suggested before although I couldn't find it.<br><br>Upon getting a notification change the pages HTML head title could change to an appended number of notifications in round brackets ().<br><br>For example if I get a notification, the HTML head title in my browser tabs would change from Hack Forums to Hack Forums (1), making me clearly see that I have a notification awaiting.", 1000)
    omniTextAnswers("Can't you just click the fugging tab?", "@Xerotic can you look into this?", "We could make a bytes fee to have this function.")
    listeners(pageTen);
}

function pageTen() {

    document.querySelector(".avatar7").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".avatar8").style.display = "";
    checkAnswer231(x);
    omniText(rightText, null, "0px solid green", 0300);
    stanleyText("Any fans of Death Note here? I thought it was a fantastic Anime and very refreshing for me. I really wish they would of made it longer though.", 1000);
    omniTextAnswers("I don't really get Anime, seems pointless.", "Anime is for retards.", "I'm not a fan of Anime but I totally get why people may like them.");
    listeners(pageEleven);
}

function pageEleven() {

}


}


init();
```

Comment: Your first and third snippet appear to be missing the closing brace

Comment: Yes but they don't in the original code sorry.

Comment: Where is `pageTwo` called? Please add that code as well

Comment: @Bergi thanks for helping out, I've pasted a simplified version and the actual project itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `listeners(pageOne)`, an event listener function is registered.

Total registered functions - 1

Now when you click on the `goodAnswer` element, it registers another event listener.

Total registered functions - 2

Now when the `goodAnswer` is clicked again, it executes both these registered functions which -

1. Register more event listeners
2. Calls `checkAnswer` function

It looks like you are omitting the fact that you can register any number of event listeners. More you click on the element, the more listeners it is going to register. You will see more and more repeated `checkAnswer` calls.

Probably you should call [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) function before you add more.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Should I add the removeEventListener within the "listeners " function itself at the end?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. But if you need your `goodAnswer` element to do just one thing at a click, remove the previously added event listener before you add a new one. You might have to save your listener function reference somewhere to refer it when removing the listener.

Comment: I've added the removeEventListener but it still gets called twice. What I want is for the user to click the button then for the second page function to trigger, removing the previous EventListener so that it can be used again in the new page function without interfering with the data.

Comment: It looks like the remove function had not removed it successfully. Build a simple script that registers a listener two times. Click and see your code being called twice. Then experiment with removing the first listener before adding the second one. Finally apply what you lear to your real code.

Comment: I have defined my EventListeners called functions in the global context now. But how do I pass my page nextPage function into my event listener now?

Comment: Use `bind` and pass your function as an argument. OR, simply, save the next page function to a variable and make your listener function get the reference via that variable.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do https://pastebin.com/zus2N83H I'm new to JS, never heard of Bind will check it out now. Coding my project has taught me what I know, thanks for helping :)